# I have a native PHP function issue when I convert plain PHP code into CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a native PHP function issue when I convert plain PHP code into CodeIgniter. Do have any idea or alternate solution about this?

Plain PHP code

```
$aColumns = array( 'id', 'name', 'first_name' );
$sTable = "ajax";
$sQuery = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
          ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."FROM   $sTable
$rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery );
while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_assoc( $rResult ) )
{
  print_r($aRow);
}
```

Perfect Result Output

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => kane
    [first_name] => kane
)
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [name] => kane
    [first_name] => kane
)
Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [name] => kane
    [first_name] => kane
)
```

Codeigniter CODE

```
$aColumns = array( 'id', 'name', 'first_name' );
$sTable = "ajax";
$sQuery = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
           ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."FROM   $sTable
$rResult = $this->db->query($sQuery);
while ( $aRow =  $rResult->row_array() )
{
      print_r($aRow);
}
```

Infinite Result Output

```
Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => kane
        [first_name] => kane
    )
Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => kane
        [first_name] => kane
    )
```

Comment: The `$sQuery` line will not run in either case, the double quotes are not matched, and it is missing a trailing semi-colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because the use of `$result->row_array()` is wrong in what you're trying to accomplish.

The correct way, to loop over the results and getting the result as an array is using the `$result->result_array()` method instead. Like so:

```
foreach( $rResult->result_array() as $aRow )
{
      print_r($aRow);
}
```

Take a look at the documentation for [generating query results](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) in CI.

Answer (score 1):

Remove SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS. You don't need that as you are not limiting the result set.

```
foreach($rResult->result_array() as $aRow)
     print_r($aRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider organizing your SQL statements a little bit.

```
$this->db->select('id, name, first_name')
    ->from('ajax')

$query = $this->db->get();

$count = $query->num_rows();

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
    print_r($row);
```